# Samba File server

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing

I know, there are a lot of articles about my request but everyone is different and I am getting confused.

My question:

I’ve installed a samba server (14.04- 64 bit), the server has 1 2TB hard drive which I split in partitions, I would like to create 2 folders (say folder1 and folder 2) in / dev/sda3 (formatted as Fat32), folder1 should be accessible to everyone in the company, without password and they need full access- read, write and delete (we are an exhibition centre), folder2 should be password protected and full accessible by 2 users (say user1 and user2). What’s the best way to do this, as I am really confused from reading a lot of articles on the net (they are all different).

The other point;  as we are an exhibition and conference  center, we get a lot of clients who need to access the “ non protected” folder  (folder1) and can’t guarantee that their devices are in the same home group as the server , what’s the best way to do this?

The shared folders should be accessible by all sorts of operating systems like  Mac, Windows

Many thanks

```
    PRIMARY-AV:~$    
     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks Id    System
/dev/sda1   *        2046   100958207    50478081    5    Extended   
/dev/sda3       100958208  3907028991  1903035392    b    W95 FAT32
/dev/sda5            2048    84191231    42094592    83   Linux 
/dev/sda6       84193280   100958207     8382464   82 Linux swap/ Solaris
```

Comment: Set up `smb.conf` file.

Comment: Is there any reason you want the share to be formatted as FAT32? A samba share can be accessed from Windows, Mac and Linux irrespective of the file system. I would therefore choose something more native to the server.

Comment: Hi Bruni, to be honest, I prefere to format it to NTFS nut I did read that FAT32 is better for MAC devises. Should I go with NTFS do you think or which formating would you advice?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Bruni, to be honest, I prefere to format it to NTFS nut I did read that FAT32 is better for MAC devises, and in case of failover (e.g. server motherboard stops working) I would like to be able to connect the HD to any windows machine to be able to save files. Should I go with NTFS do you think or which formating would you advice?  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First install samba if you haven't yet.

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Scroll to the very bottom of the file and put in the following, (This is for folder 1 which is a public with no password)

```
[Share name]
writable = yes
path = /path/to/directory
public = yes
guest ok = yes
guest only = yes
guest account = nobody
browsable = yes
```

For folder 2 case add the following

```
[Share name]
writable = yes
path = /path/to/directory
public = no
guest ok = no
guest account = nobody
browsable = yes
```

Save the file and quit gedit
In the terminal restart the samba server to reload the conf file

```
sudo servicesamba restart
```

Now you have to create a samba user which is authenticated to acees shared folders

```
sudo  smbpasswd -a username
```

Comment: Many thanks New User for the quick answer, just need to know, how can I make sure that both folders are going to be in the right partition? ( /dev/sda3). Many thanks

Comment: you have to replace the path/to/direcorty with the mounting point of your /dev/sda3

Comment: @madona33 please give a feedback whether this answer is valid for you or not!! please take a look:  http://askubuntu.com/tour